# Select specific values and perform an operation in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to do a complex operation for my R knowledge. I have this `data` dataframe:

```
trial <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b_value = c("x","x","x","y","y","y")

key1 <- c("b","b","b","b","b","m")
key2 <- c("n","m","m","n",NA,"b")
key3 <- c("b",NA,"n",NA,NA,NA)
key4 <- c("b",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

dur1 <- c(2,3,5,6,0,0)
dur2 <- c(1,6,3,2,0,0)
dur3 <- c(2,3,5,0,0,0)
dur4 <- c(2,3,0,0,0,0)

data <- data.frame(trial,b_value, key1, key2, key3, key4, dur1, dur2, dur3, dur4)
```

These data refer to key pressing, so for example the duration of `key1` (b, n or m) is `dur1` in each trial.
I have to sum each key duration (**b** for example) for each row and creating a new column with total **b** time. This for each key in each row.
How can I do it?

Comment: What happens to `NA`s and could you post what the final output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution involving `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  gather(key="key_no", value="key", starts_with("key")) %>% 
  gather(key="dur_no", value="duration", starts_with("dur")) %>% 
  mutate(key_no = str_replace(key_no, "key", ""),
         dur_no = str_replace(dur_no, "dur", "")) %>% 
  filter(dur_no == key_no) %>% # Assumes that the duration and the key have linked numbers
  arrange(trial, key) %>% 
  group_by(trial, key) %>% 
  summarise(total_duration = sum(duration))
```

This produces the following ouptut:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   trial [6]
   trial key   total_duration
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
 1     1 b                  6
 2     1 n                  1
 3     2 NA                 6
 4     2 b                  3
 5     2 m                  6
 6     3 NA                 0
 7     3 b                  5
 8     3 m                  3
 9     3 n                  5
10     4 NA                 0
11     4 b                  6
12     4 n                  2
13     5 NA                 0
14     5 b                  0
15     6 NA                 0
16     6 b                  0
...
```

Note the two `gather()` options + the `filter()` that makes sure you don't have too many rows.

Answer (score 0):

## Using base R:

```
#If you want the output in one summative table.
total_duration <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(grep("^key",names(data)))) {
  for (j in 1:length(na.omit(unique(data[,paste0("key",i)])))) {
    dat <- sum(
      data[data[,paste0("key",i)] == na.omit(unique(data[,paste0("key",i)]))[j],
           paste0("dur",i)], na.rm = TRUE)
#make a new variable name
    newname <- paste0( 
      paste0(
        "key",i
        ), na.omit(unique(data[,paste0("key",i)]))[j])
      )
    total_duration[newname] <- dat
  }
}

as.data.frame(total_duration)

      total_duration
key1b             16
key1m              0
key2n              3
key2m              9
key2b              0
key3b              2
key3n              5
key4b              2
```